# Use of UIActivityViewController and UIActivityItemProvider to share PDF

Tags: ios, swift

I need to share/open some different files under iOS e.g. an image to iCloud or an pdf to iBooks. There are several examples around for text and images but nothing for somewhat else...

I created my own `UIActivityItemProvider`; simplified version here:

```
class MyItemProvider: UIActivityItemProvider {

  override func item() -> AnyObject {
    self.placeholderItem
  }

  override func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType activityType: String?) -> String {
    return kUTTypePDF as String
  }

  func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
    return self.placeholderItem
  }
}
```

And start sharing with something like:

```
let myPDF = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("testpdf", withExtension: "pdf")) {
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [MyItemProvider(placeHolder: myPDF)], applicationActivities: nil)
self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I expect a sharedialog like:

[image]

But all I get is:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Documentation says that providing NSData (and only NSData) will trigger a call for `dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType` - but that's not true. Also NSURL will trigger that. Providing NSURL instead of NSData will show at least most installed Apps - except "save to iBooks".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**

### Share a PDF with UIActivityViewController in Swift 3

**

I've spent a lot of time thinking ways to share a PDF file within UIWebView loaded from a URL, like "http://youPdfFile.pdf"

After a coupe of days, I've found what I think it's the most suitable way:

**1) The PDF must first be saved in the file system. For example, this can be done after loading the UIWebView:**

```
class yourViewController: UIViewController{
       var documentPathToLoad = "http://youPdfFile.pdf"
       ...

       func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) { 
           if yourWebView.isLoading { 
               // still loading 
               return 
           } 

           //Save the pdf document to file system 
           savePdf() 
       }

       func savePdf(){    
           let fileManager = FileManager.default 
           let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomain((.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("documento.pdf") 
           let pdfDoc = NSData(contentsOf:URL(string: documentPathToLoad)!) 
           fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths as String, contents: pdfDoc as Data?, attributes: nil) 
       } 
}
```

**2) Read the saved file and then share it. This method works for me in  Swift 3.0.1:**

```
func loadPDFAndShare(){ 

           let fileManager = FileManager.default 
           let documentoPath = (self.getDirectoryPath() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("documento.pdf") 

           if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: documentoPath){              
                let documento = NSData(contentsOfFile: documentoPath) 
                let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [documento!], applicationActivities: nil) 
                activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView=self.view 
                present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
            } 
            else { 
                print("document was not found") 
            } 
        }
```

Comment: getDirectoryPath() where is this function ?  i got an error

Comment: Hi @DhavalUmraliya, the function is this: func getDirectoryPath() -> String {
        
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentsDirectory
    }

Comment: I only got the correct file name using `UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [documentoPath!]` instead of `UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [documento!]`

Answer (score 14):

The existing answers demonstrate how to share a PDF using a local file's URL. However you don't have to create a file if you don't want to. The alternative is to use `Data` representation of your PDF file.

Let's say your're using `PDFKit` to display PDFs in UI. It means that you would deal with `PDFKit.PDFDocument` class which has `dataRepresentation()` method. This method returns `Data` which can be passed to `UIActivityViewController` initialiser.

Answer (score 9):

You have to pass **pdf file url** for pdf supported applications' options in UIActivityViewController.

```
func btnTapped() {
    if let pdf = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "yourPdfFileName", withExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)  {
        self.sharePdf(path: pdf)
    }
}    

func sharePdf(path:URL) {

    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path.path) {
        let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [path], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        print("document was not found")
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Document was not found!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        UIViewController.hk_currentViewController()?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This code works for me to share a file. Of course the file has to already have been created:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", @"FileName"]];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath];
NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:URL, nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```