# iOS UIDocumentInteractionController PDF sharing issue

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I want to share saved PDF in app. actually it was not working on PRINT and also on MAIL it was working with sharing over Whatsapp and other app.

```
{
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let imagePAth = (Common.getDirectoryPath() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("invoice.pdf")
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagePAth){
        let url = URL (fileURLWithPath: localurlfile)
        docController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: url)
        docController.presentOptionsMenu(from: self.view.frame, in: self.view, animated: true)
    }else{
        print("No Image")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share contents using UIActivityViewController.

```
if let pdfFileUrl = URL(String("yourFileURL")) {
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfFileUrl], applicationActivities: [])
present(vc, animated: true)`enter code here`
```

}

Refer this for more info.
[Use of UIActivityViewController and UIActivityItemProvider to share PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990711/use-of-uiactivityviewcontroller-and-uiactivityitemprovider-to-share-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

To view and sharing purpose.

```
let controller = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: pdfurl)
controller.delegate = self
controller.presentPreview(animated: true)
```

And implement UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate.

```
extension ViewController: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        return self
    }

    func documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) {
    }
}
```